# Magento 1.7.0.2 CE - PayPal IPN stopped working

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-ipn

I built and maintain a Magento 1.7.0.2 CE online shop.
Magento is installed in a shop/ sub-directory.

Until a few weeks ago the PayPal IPN (Standard) changed orders from "pending payment" to "processing" without problems.
Now orders stay with a status of "pending payment" even when payed.

I changed the paths in
web-root/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php
from

```
$api->setOrderId($orderIncrementId)
    ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
    //->setPaymentAction()
    ->setOrder($order)
    ->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))
    ->setReturnUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/standard/success'))
    ->setCancelUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/standard/cancel'));
```

to

```
$api->setOrderId($orderIncrementId)
    ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
    //->setPaymentAction()
    ->setOrder($order)
    ->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('shop/paypal/ipn/'))
    ->setReturnUrl(Mage::getUrl('shop/paypal/standard/success'))
    ->setCancelUrl(Mage::getUrl('shop/paypal/standard/cancel'));
```

but that did not fix the problem.

A fresh Magento 1.7.0.2 CE installation verified that PayPal is configured correctly. The test order changed from "pending payment" to "processing".

Where else could I look to find the problem in the production shop?